# How do I skip this line when Userform is blank?

Tags: excel, vba

How do I skip these lines in my codes? So I have a userform where it will input data but for some of the data there a percent. So I set it up like this:

```
With Sheets("Test")
      .cells(7,lrCal).Value = tbAvP.Text / 100
      .cells(8,lrcal).Value = tbAcc.Text / 100
end With
```

I understand that the error is that the code read blank equal to zero. How would I bypass this if there a blank in the userform?

Comment: `If Not IsEmpty(whatever)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add an IF statement:

```
With Sheets("Test")
    If .Cells(7, lrCal).Value <> "" or .Cells(8, lrCal).Value <> "" Then
        [your code]
    End IF
End With
```

You might need to break that in to two separate statements, if one can be blank, and you want to calculate the other.  But the above should give you general idea on how to handle this.

Edit: Or, as @Damian noted in a comment, you can use `If Not IsEmpty([cell ref]) or Not IsEmpty([other cell ref]) Then`

Comment: I'm missing something. OP says the "blank" is "in the userform", i.e. the textboxes contain an empty string (which isn't `Empty` and won't work with `IsEmpty`) -- but then accepts this answer which checks whether the cells about to be written to, are empty. I'm... confused.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon - I was actually just thinking the same. I referenced cells, not userform. ...but it got accepted...?  Maybe just the idea of using an "If" statement hadn't occurred to OP, so *that's* the part that helped?  I think instead they could do `If tbAvP.Text <> "" ...`?